# How do I find P(a<x<b) with a mean of 10 and a standard deviation of 2 for a normal distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

Mean = u = 10 std = o = 2

Finding a and b such that P(a<x<b) = 0.90 and |u-a| = |u-b|

So I looked at a Z table and found 0.90 sitting between a Z-Score of 1.28 and 1.29. I added those values up and took the average so that.

1.28 = 0.899727432 and 1.29 = 0.901474671

(0.899727432 + 0.901474671) / 2 = 0.9006010515

Z= 1.285

Then I used the standard normal equation.

Z=(x-u)/o

where x = b

1.285 = (b - 10) / 2

b = 2(1.285) + 10

b= 12.57

Are A and B the same then? I'm not sure I'm approaching this problem correctly.

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE. You are on the right track in general that you started by letting Z following N(0, 1), trying to find c and d such that $P(c<Z<d)=0.9$ using a z-table, and convert $c,d$ to $a,b$ by taking the inverse of the standard score function. However, you might not have read the z-table correctly - most z-tables give you the probability of seeing values from _negative infinity_ up to your tabled value, and you want to ditch part of the said probability density in your question.

Comment: Do you have access to any of (1) a z-table which shows the z-value for specific quantiles (0.9, 0.95, 0.99), (2) a calculator that calculates $P(c<Z<d)$ or at least $P(Z<d)$ for any given $c$ and $d$, or (3) a programming library that does (2)?

Comment: I have access to  https://www.ztable.net, as to a calculator that calculated P(c < Z < d) I do not as I believe I'm supposed to be learning how to do this by hand.

I believe since the total probabilty is 0.90, the probability of P(a<x) = 0.45 and P(b>x) = 0.45.

Comment: Your understanding of splitting the probability density of 0.9 into two equal halves is sound, but the way you expressed it (i.e., $P(a<X) = 0.45$ and $P(X<b) = 0.45$)) will lead to something totally different as you have not bounded the values of $X$ correctly. Draw a normal distribution (be it with (mean, variance) = (10, 2) or (0, 1)) on a paper, can you sketch which region you want your 0.9 probability to cover, at what value you are splitting them in two 0.45 halves, and express the probability expressions using the bounds you have found? Hint: the expressions should involve $\mu$.

Comment: I have it figured out thank you.  https://imgur.com/UusNMaQ

Answer (score 0):

P(X<b) = 0.95

Z = 1.645

1.645 = (b-10)/2

2(1.645) + 10 = b

13.25 = b

P(x>a) = 1 - 0.95 P(x<a) = 0.05

Z for 0.05 is -1.64

2(-1.64)+10 = a

a = 6.72

Comment: It may be helpful to add more clarifying detail to your answer. Of course showing an answer directly illustrates the solution, but it may benefit others if you explain why it worked :)

Comment: Thank you, I will come back to this and add more clarifying detail as it will help me also better understand.